# updating data based on on column is null or not null

Tags: sql, oracle

I am updating table on column based on whether column is empty or null.
if null then will take direct any data .if not null means it will take existing then current data + new data.i was doing this using decode it was working fine.
but column datatype when 'clob' it is not working. An alternative to achieve this.

for ex 
      ID  Data

```
  11   ab
  15   null
```

Now if i want upate data for id 11 it should old data + new data ie  ab:cd
: this to seperate new and old
NOw if i want to update data for id 15 it should  only new data ie=  ef

```
 UPDATE TESTING 
 SET DATA = decode( DATA ,null,'CONFIRM',DATA||sysdate||'test' ) 
 WHERE  ID=15;
```

where data is column checking .Could any one please guide how to do this in clob data type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Case` statements. This is just a pseudo code

```
 UPDATE TESTING 
 SET DATA = Case when DATA IS NULL then direct any data 
                 Else existing then current data + new data 
            End
 WHERE  ID=15;
```

Comment: UPDATE TESTING 
 SET DATA = case when DATA IS NULL "great" 
                 Else DATA||"great"
                 End
 WHERE  ID=15;

Comment: @AnimeshSheolikar You missed `then` between `IS NULL` and  `"great"`. It should be `..IS NULL then "great"..`

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NVL2 function:

```
UPDATE TESTING
 SET DATA = NVL2( DATA, DATA||sysdate||'test', 'CONFIRM' )
 WHERE  ID=15;
```

Comment: Wow it work like a charm .Thanks@Sentinel  i was trying with NVL2 but may syntax was wrong.Thanks again

Comment: @AnimeshSheolikar, your welcome.  You can show your appreciation by upvoting my answer, and/or marking it as accepted.

Comment: i would love to do that i dont have enough reputations.

Comment: I know the feeling I've only recently gotten enough reputation to do much,